# Endless loop in react and socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, use-state

I'm trying to build a realtime chat message. In the client's side (React), whenever a new user enters the chat, the socket's event **usuarios-conectados** gets triggered (this socket event gives me an array of all the users connected at the time).

Then, I tried to set that array of users in a **useState**, but because of that, the component goes into a loop and keeps re-rendering itself.

That seems to be the problem because whenever i call **useSocket**, the **console.log(users)** keeps printing the connected users over and over

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export const useSockets = () => {

    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(
        io('http://localhost:8080', {
            'extraHeaders': {
                'x-token': localStorage.getItem('x-token')
            }
        })
    )

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Sockets online')
        })

        socket.on('usuarios-conectados', (newUsers) => {

            setUsers(newUsers);
            console.log(users);
        })

        return () => {

            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                console.log('Sockets offline')
            })
            socket.disconnect()
        }
    }, [])


    return [users]
}
```

Comment: I've resolved it and described in my blog https://alfilatov.com/posts/frontend-dto-challenge/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not store io in a state instead create a file and import in your component and then after you initialize the socket itself will listen to events that you define. let me show in code.

```
//src/utils/socket.js
import io from "socket.io-client"
export const socket = io(process.env.BACKURL);

// component.jsx
import {socket} from './utils/socket'
 const [commentData , setCommentData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   socket.on("connect_error", () => {
    console.error("socket error!");
    socket.close();
  });

  // websokcet to comments
  socket.on("load_comment", (payload) => {
    setCommentData(payload);
  });
 return () => {
 socket.close();
}
}, [])
// second useEffect to see if statesChanged
useEffect(() => {
 console.log('Changed' , commentData)
} , [commentData])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not store the IO in a state but call it in a context, for example, let me show in code.

1. Create a context

```js
import React from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
        
const SOCKET_ADDR = process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_ADDR || '<your server>';
        
export const socket = io(SOCKET_ADDR, { withCredentials: false, transports: ['websocket'] });
        
export const SocketContext = React.createContext();
```

2. And add it wherever you want

```js
import { SocketContext, socket } from './socket/SocketContext';

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.on('welcome', (res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    });
});
```